# What type of wall is this?

Tags: drywall, wood, blinds

I'm installing blinds that will mount in the ceiling (inside) of the window pane. I initially used wood screws but then thought I'd use drywall screws for greater strength. I tried drilling a hole to push the drywall anchor in and am now confused. Please help!

Edit: Through lot of reading up, this is drywall backed by concrete. The metal strip howing through (bottom of picture) is the corner bead.

[image: Looking upwards to the window pane head]

Comment: Does “ceiling inside of the window pane” mean the “window header” ?

Comment: Yes Lee - the window header.

Comment: LOL you live in Europe don't you? The land of craptastic concrete and fiberboard. Did you file all the forms with the local officials requesting permission to modify your dwelling?

Comment: This is in Toronto. So this is fiberboard then? So I use regular screws and not drywall screws?

Comment: Is this in a single family residence or in a condo? Are we looking at the bottom of the header (looking up) or are we looking at the side of the header? In other words, are you looking for shear strength or pullout strength?

Comment: Hi @LeeSam. We're looking upwards towards the ceiling. This is a condo in Toronto. I am sorry - I don't know the difference between sheer and pullout strength. All I want is for the blinds to hold well when mounted to the ceiling.

Comment: @LeeSam - I've attached a higher resolution zoomed in pic. When I drilled the hole deeper, I hit what looks like concrete or some metal. I could not push a drywall anchor in.

Comment: Drywall screws are NOT strong. They break easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind the plasterboard (drywall) it looks like it could be the metal of either  an RSJ or a *Catnic*. Either could have been used to support the brickwork over the window aperature. If it's a Catnic, it'll be possible to drill through, and use self-tappers to secure the blinds. If it's an RSJ, the steel will be quite thick, and will take a long while to drill holes for screws.

A drilled Catnic could have a larger hole through which you could push a drywall fitting - a longer one, so it expanded on the other side of the thin steel.

If it's an RSJ, there's also the possibility of drilling and tapping, so a bolt can be threaded into it. A very strong fixing, but maybe beyond diy.

You may be better off trying to fix into the *sides* of the reveal - at the very top, which may just be drywall - but needs a different blind fixture.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Tim! Much appreciated.